# C# Duplication of generic parameter in class declaration

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm playing with C# generics and interfaces today and trying implement classic definition of [Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Graph). Here is my best attempt (for exercise only):

```
interface IVertex
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IEdge<V> where V : IVertex
{
    V From { get; set; }
    V To { get; set; }
}

interface IGraph<V, E> where E: IEdge<V> where V: IVertex
{
    IList<V> Vertices { get; }
    IList<E> Edges { get; }
}

class Vertex : IVertex
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Vertex(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Edge<V> : IEdge<V> where V: IVertex
{
    public V From { get; set; }
    public V To { get; set; }

    public Edge(V from, V to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}

class Graph<V, E> : IGraph<V, E> where E: IEdge<V> where V : IVertex
{
    public IList<V> Vertices { get; } = new List<V>();
    public IList<E> Edges { get; } = new List<E>();
}
```

But I think, that I'm doing something wrong, because in following usage:

```
var a = new Vertex("A");
var b = new Vertex("B");
var c = new Vertex("C");

var x = new Edge<Vertex>(a, b);
var y = new Edge<Vertex>(b, c);
var z = new Edge<Vertex>(c, a);

var graph = new Graph<Vertex, Edge<Vertex>>()
{
    Vertices = { a, b, c },
    Edges = {x, y, z}
};
```

I need to specify the generic argument `Vertex` (at line `new Graph<Vertex, Edge<Vertex>>()`) twice...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that (or at least not *per se*). What might help is writing `Edge : IEdge<Vertex>` such that the generic parameter can be omitted (so omitting the type parameter at the `Edge` class level).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Alejandro I think the question is more about the template (or generic) specialization for the graph class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context, it's not clear what your constraints and requirements are. But, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, the syntax you currently have may be required, to ensure that your `IList<E>` is declared appropriately.

It is also possible that you *don't* require the `Graph` class to have the exact `IEdge<V>` type. If so, then you could declare it like this:

```
class Graph<V> : IGraph<V, IEdge<V>> where V : IVertex
{
    public IList<V> Vertices { get; } = new List<V>();
    public IList<IEdge<V>> Edges { get; } = new List<IEdge<V>>();
}
```

In this approach, you will not be able e.g. to assign `Edges` to a variable of type `IList<E>` where `E` is some type other than `IEdge<V>`. For example, this wouldn't work, while it would work if you require both types to be specified:

```
IList<Edge<Vertex>> list = graph.Edges;
```

It all depends on how you actually want to use these types.